# how do I use babel 6 (es7) plugins like the (es6) polyfill?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

**Problem**

I have a reasonable amount of experience using Babel in my projects, but I've come across a situation which I am not sure about:

I have an *es5 project*, which has a *dependency* of an *es7 node module* (a deployment tool).

I want the es5 project to use the es7 module without "polluting" the es5 project with Babel infrastructure.

If my deployment tool module only used es6, I could include the [es6 polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

But as there is not es7 polyfill it looks like i should be using [plugins] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-array-includes).

---

**EDIT #1**: As an analogy: If I was using coffeescript, I'd just transpile and save the output in `my-coffee-module/dist/index.min.js`. How could I do the same with Babel?

I'd perfer to not use the CLI, or another tool (like rollupjs - which is good, but it seems unnecessary).

---

**Previous work**

When I put a `.babelrc` in my module (or use the *require hook*):

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
    presets: ['babel-preset-es2015'],
    plugins: ["array-includes"]
});
```

and then use it from my es5 project I get:

```
ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "babel-array-includes" specified in "base" at 0
```

If I use the API (via gulp-babel) I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at exports.default (/Users/me/deploy-tool/node_modules/babel-plugin-array-includes/lib/index.js:11:10)
```

which is a complaint about `Plugin` being undefined in the plugin :

```
  /*
   ... babel-plugin-array-includes/lib/index.js: lines 11-13
  */
  return new Plugin("array-includes", {
      metadata: {
        group: "builtin-post"
      },
```

Any advice or opinion would be appreciated, thanks

**EDIT #2: Partial solution**: It seems it is not possible without using the [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) at this time, which I will do with [npm build scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build).

I'll leave this question open, pending my [github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2837).